# Espresso tests with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

Every time I try to test my Android app and I rewrite my tests in Kotlin I always get:

> Class not found: "my.package.modules.container.ContainerViewInstrumentedTest"
>   Empty test suite.

I am trying everything to make Espresso see my tests... but no luck. Does anyone know what can be wrong?

Comment: can you share how your testclass looks like?

Comment: Check the test package espresso tests must be placed in the `app/src/androidTest` folder and also check your default constructor should not have any parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not my tests... There was something wrong with Android Studio - Canary1... It is fixed now in the Canary 4

When it doesn't work in AS, running in the command line normally work.

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```